# (Unity XR Interaction Toolkit) Make a hand Ungrab an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, toolkit

Hi I'm actually making a VR game in Unity (in C#).

I currently have an item that I'd like the player to be able to duplicate when he grasps it with two hands and then spreads them apart sufficiently.
So once the first object has been grabbed with two hands, the second hand has to unhook itself from the first object so that I can instantiate the Prefab of the same item in this second hand.

I tried going through the XRBaseInteractor of the hand concerned, using the allowSelect = false, enableInteractions = false and even Set Active(false) methods.

but as soon as I set these parameters to true, I find that the hand is still holding the object.
Even destroying the gameObject to instentiate another one doesn't make the hand ungrab...

How can I disable one hand without affecting the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
interactionManager.SelectExit(interactor, interactable);
```